# run perl -e from inside perl script in windows

Tags: windows, perl

I need to run the following command from inside a Perl script in Windows. The code can't be simpler than this:

```
#! C:\Perl\bin\perl

perl -e "print qq(Hello)";
```

I save this file as `test.pl`. I open a command prompt in Windows and run the following from the `c:\Per\bin` directory. When I run it as `perl test.pl`, I get the following result:

```
C:\Perl\bin>perl test.pl
syntax error at test.pl line 3, near ""perl -e "print"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

How can I fix this? If I just run `perl -e` from the command prompt (i.e. without being inside the file) it works great.

Comment: If you were running the script through perl (as the error shows), `perl` is not a command that Perl knows. It also tells you this. What could you possibly do in an `-e` that you can't do in a script?!?! The reason it runs great on the command line is that the OS considers `perl` a "command" if it can find it in the PATH. And `perl -e` is expected to "run great" from the command line--unlike in perl.

Answer (score 4):

The `test.pl` file should contain:

```
print qq(Hello);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to run perl code with `perl -e …`? Just put the actual code in your program.

If, on the other hand, you want to run an external command from within your program, then the answer depends on what you want to do with the input/output and/or the exit code of your program. Have a look at [system](http://p3rl.org/system), [qx](http://p3rl.org/qx) and [open](http://p3rl.org/opentut).

Answer (score 2):

To run another program from your Perl program, use the [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) operator that has a nice feature for bypassing the command shell's argument parsing.

> If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the program given by the first element of the list with arguments given by the rest of the list. If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing …

For example:

```
#! perl

system("perl", "-le", "print qq(Hello)") == 0
  or warn "$0: perl exited " . ($? >> 8);
```

Remember that `system` runs the command with its output going to the standard output. If you want to capture the output, do so as in

```
open my $fh, "-|", "perl", "-le", "print qq(Hello)"
  or die "$0: could not start perl: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
  print "got: $_";
}

close $fh or warn "$0: close: $!";
```

As with `system`, opening a command specified as a multi-element list bypasses the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need it but:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl

`perl -e "print qq(Hello)"`;
```

Comment: or `system perl => -e => qq{"print qq(Hello)"}` depending on where the OP wants the output to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)?